# Calculate the approximate entropy of a matrix of time series

Tags: r, matrix

Approximate entropy was introduced to quantify the the amount of regularity and the unpredictability of fluctuations in a time series.

The function

```
approx_entropy(ts, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(ts), elag = 1)
```

from package `pracma`, calculates the approximate entropy of time series `ts`.

I have a matrix of time series (one series per row) `mat` and I would estimate the approximate entropy for each of them, storing the results in a vector. For example:

```
library(pracma)

N<-nrow(mat)
r<-matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = 1)
for (i in 1:N){
     r[i]<-approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
}
```

However, if `N` is large this code could be too slow. Suggestions to speed it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also say parallelization, as apply-functions apparently didn't bring any optimization.

I tried the `approx_entropy()` function with:

- apply
- lapply
- ParApply
- foreach (from @Mankind_008)
- a combination of data.table and ParApply

The `ParApply` seems to be **slightly more efficient** than the other 2 parallel functions.

As I didn't get the same timings as @Mankind_008 I checked them with `microbenchmark`.
Those were the results for 10 runs:

> ```
> Unit: seconds
> expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
> forloop     4.067308 4.073604 4.117732 4.097188 4.141059 4.244261    10   b
> apply       4.054737 4.092990 4.147449 4.139112 4.188664 4.246629    10   b
> lapply      4.060242 4.068953 4.229806 4.105213 4.198261 4.873245    10   b
> par         2.384788 2.397440 2.646881 2.456174 2.558573 4.134668    10   a 
> parApply    2.289028 2.300088 2.371244 2.347408 2.369721 2.675570    10   a 
> DT_parApply 2.294298 2.322774 2.387722 2.354507 2.466575 2.515141    10   a
> ```

[image: Different Methods]

---

Full Code:

```
library(pracma)
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)


# dummy random time series data
ts <- rnorm(56)
mat <- matrix(rep(ts,100), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
r <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(mat), ncol = 1)      


## For Loop
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)){     
  r[i]<-approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
}

## Apply
r1 = apply(mat, 1, FUN = function(x) approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1))

## Lapply
r2 = lapply(1:nrow(mat), FUN = function(x) approx_entropy(mat[x,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[x,]), elag = 1))

## ParApply
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
  library(pracma); 
  approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
})
stopCluster(cl)

## Foreach
registerDoParallel(cl = 3, cores = 2)  
r4 <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(mat), .combine = rbind)  %dopar%  
  pracma::approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
stopImplicitCluster()  

## Data.table
library(data.table)
mDT = as.data.table(mat)
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
r5 = parApply(cl = cl, mDT, 1, FUN = function(x) {
  library(pracma); 
  approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
})
stopCluster(cl)


## All equal Tests
all.equal(as.numeric(r), r1)
all.equal(r1, as.numeric(do.call(rbind, r2)))
all.equal(r1, r3)
all.equal(r1, as.numeric(r4))
all.equal(r1, r5)


## Benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times=10,
  forloop = {
    for (i in 1:nrow(mat)){
      r[i]<-approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
    }
  },
  apply = {
    r1 = apply(mat, 1, FUN = function(x) approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1))
  },
  lapply = {
    r1 = lapply(1:nrow(mat), FUN = function(x) approx_entropy(mat[x,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[x,]), elag = 1))
  },
  par = {
    registerDoParallel(cl = 3, cores = 2)  
    r_par <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(mat), .combine = rbind)  %dopar%  
      pracma::approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
    stopImplicitCluster()
  }, 
  parApply = {
    cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
    r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
      library(pracma); 
      approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
    })
    stopCluster(cl)
  },
  DT_parApply = {
    mDT = as.data.table(mat)
    cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
    r5 = parApply(cl = cl, mDT, 1, FUN = function(x) {
      library(pracma); 
      approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
    })
    stopCluster(cl)
  }
)

## Results
mc
Unit: seconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
forloop 4.067308 4.073604 4.117732 4.097188 4.141059 4.244261    10   b
apply 4.054737 4.092990 4.147449 4.139112 4.188664 4.246629    10   b
lapply 4.060242 4.068953 4.229806 4.105213 4.198261 4.873245    10   b
par 2.384788 2.397440 2.646881 2.456174 2.558573 4.134668    10  a 
parApply 2.289028 2.300088 2.371244 2.347408 2.369721 2.675570    10  a 
DT_parApply 2.294298 2.322774 2.387722 2.354507 2.466575 2.515141    10  a 

## Time-Boxplot
plot(mc)
```

---

The **amount of cores** will also affect speed, and more is not always faster, as at some point, the overhead that is sent to all workers eats away some of the gained performance. I benchmarked the `ParApply` function with 2 to 7 cores, and on my machine, running the function with 3 / 4 cores seems to be the best choice, althouth the deviation is not that big.

> ```
> mc
> Unit: seconds
> expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
> parApply_2 2.670257 2.688115 2.699522 2.694527 2.714293 2.740149    10   c 
> parApply_3 2.312629 2.366021 2.411022 2.399599 2.464568 2.535220    10 a   
> parApply_4 2.358165 2.405190 2.444848 2.433657 2.485083 2.568679    10 a   
> parApply_5 2.504144 2.523215 2.546810 2.536405 2.558630 2.646244    10  b  
> parApply_6 2.687758 2.725502 2.761400 2.747263 2.766318 2.969402    10   c 
> parApply_7 2.906236 2.912945 2.948692 2.919704 2.988599 3.053362    10    d
> ```

[image: Amount of Cores]

Full Code:

```
## Benchmark N-Cores
library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times=10,
                     parApply_2 = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     },
                     parApply_3 = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     },
                     parApply_4 = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 4))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     },
                     parApply_5 = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 5))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     },
                     parApply_6 = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 6))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     },
                     parApply_7 = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 7))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     }
)

## Results
mc
Unit: seconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
parApply_2 2.670257 2.688115 2.699522 2.694527 2.714293 2.740149    10   c 
parApply_3 2.312629 2.366021 2.411022 2.399599 2.464568 2.535220    10 a   
parApply_4 2.358165 2.405190 2.444848 2.433657 2.485083 2.568679    10 a   
parApply_5 2.504144 2.523215 2.546810 2.536405 2.558630 2.646244    10  b  
parApply_6 2.687758 2.725502 2.761400 2.747263 2.766318 2.969402    10   c 
parApply_7 2.906236 2.912945 2.948692 2.919704 2.988599 3.053362    10    d

## Plot Results
plot(mc)
```

---

As the **matrices get bigger**, using `ParApply` with `data.table` seems to be faster than using matrices. The following example used a matrix with 500*500 elements resulting in those timings (only for 2 runs):

> ```
> Unit: seconds
> expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
> ParApply 191.5861 191.5861 192.6157 192.6157 193.6453 193.6453     2   a
> DT_ParAp 135.0570 135.0570 163.4055 163.4055 191.7541 191.7541     2   a
> ```

The minimum is considerably lower, although the maximum is almost the same which is also nicely illustrated in that boxplot:
[image]

Full Code:

```
# dummy random time series data
ts <- rnorm(500)
# mat <- matrix(rep(ts,100), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
mat = matrix(rep(ts,500), nrow = 500, ncol = 500, byrow = T)
r <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(mat), ncol = 1)      

## Benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times=2,
                     ParApply = {
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
                       r3 = parApply(cl = cl, mat, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     },
                     DT_ParAp = {
                       mDT = as.data.table(mat)
                       cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 3))
                       r5 = parApply(cl = cl, mDT, 1, FUN = function(x) {
                         library(pracma); 
                         approx_entropy(x, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1)
                       })
                       stopCluster(cl)
                     }
)

## Results
mc
Unit: seconds
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
ParApply 191.5861 191.5861 192.6157 192.6157 193.6453 193.6453     2   a
DT_ParAp 135.0570 135.0570 163.4055 163.4055 191.7541 191.7541     2   a

## Plot
plot(mc)
```

Answer (score 2):

***Parallelization*** *would speed things up*.

**Current System Time**: *without parallelization*

```
library(pracma)

ts <- rnorm(10000)                                       # dummy random time series data

mat <- matrix(ts, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
r <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(mat), ncol = 1)               # to collect response


system.time ( for (i in 1:nrow(mat)){                    # system time:  for loop
      r[i]<-approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
                        } ) 

 user  system elapsed 
31.17    6.28   65.09
```

**New System Time:** ***with parallelization***

Using ***foreach*** and its back-end parallelization package ***doParallel*** to control resources.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cl = 3, cores = 2)                      # initiate resources

system.time (
       r_par <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(mat), .combine = rbind)  %dopar%  
                pracma::approx_entropy(mat[i,], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(mat[i,]), elag = 1)
            )

stopImplicitCluster()                                      # terminate resources

user  system elapsed 
0.13    0.03   29.88
```

**P.S.** *I would recommend setting up the cluster, core allocations as per your configuration and speed requirements.*

*Also the reason I didn't include the comparison with **apply** family is because of their sequential nature in implementation, that would produce only a marginal improvement. For a considerable improvement in speed, shifting from a sequential to parallelized implementation is recommended.*